# How can I track the location of a mouse connected to an iPad/iPhone?

Tags: ios, uiview

I'd like to make an element appear when the pointer is hovering over it.

I don't know which method I should use to capture it.

For example, **UIPanGestureRecognizer** doesn't work because you have to click first.

In macOS it's inside an NSEvent object:

```
NSPoint touchPoint = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
```

Any ideas where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't solve the problem suggested by the title but it solves my problem:

```
UIHoverGestureRecognizer *hoverGestureRecognizer =
    [[UIHoverGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hover:)];

[element addGestureRecognizer:hoverGestureRecognizer];

// ...
```